# How can I have access to Github API using just login and password?

Tags: github-projects, hubpress

Is it still possible to send login and password and get access to github API as Hubpress used to do?

How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, GitHub requires to use token instead of legacy password.

You can use this token as a password for many app.